# C++ primer dynamic array number of initializers exceeds the size

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

In C++ primer 5 edition. chapter 12 Dynamic memory:

> If there are fewer
>   initializers than elements, the remaining elements are value initialized. If there are more initializers than the given size, then the new expression fails and no storage is allocated. In this case, new throws an exception of type bad_array_new_length.
>   Like bad_alloc, this type is defined in the new header.

This is about allocating and initializing Dynamic arrays. But I think it is incorrect: If the number of initializers is greater than the size of the dynamic-array then this is a compile-time error rather than a runtime error:

```
auto p = new int[3]{4, 5, 6, 7}; // compile-time error: Too many initializers.
```

Comment: ok. So.. what is the question? Whether your're correct?

Comment: Yes, I got also compile-time error...

Comment: @WhozCraig: The question? I am learning and I love this book But I want always be clear. I am not judging the writer but I want to be more precise. How could I improve learning incorrect stuff?

Comment: Stan Lippman writes good stuff, and his primers have been evolving for a long time. If you think this is an issue (it has all the makings of it), it's rare by his standards. I'd check the errata of the book, and if its not in there, let his publisher know. Regarding being careful how to not learn disinformation (rare trait these days, especially in youth), keep doing what you're doing. Check sources and verify claims, just like you did. I'd go one step further and see what the actual language standard claims.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Look at the answer below. I was mistaken. Because he was talking a bout passing non-constant size where it cannot be evaluated at compile-time thus if at runtime that size is smaller than the number if initializers then `new` throws.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa if that was what Lippman was referring to, either he, or you, left that context out of the citation you posted. If it's the former, it should be clearer in the book (I don't own it, so you'll have to judge that), and the publisher should be notified regardless. It's an interesting topic, especially to see what the standard says about the specific case you're describing vs what the book is describing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be a compile-time error, in case you use constants for the array size and compiler can clearly tell you there's a problem.

However, there are a lot of cases, when the size of the allocated memory is not constant, but rather a variable that cannot be deduced at compile time. In this case the exception will be thrown at the run time.

Comment: Ok Ok this what  makes me satisfied. Really awesome. I didn't think about passing non-const size. Thank you so much.